# Automating HPALM Tasks with UFT

Tags: vb.net, hp-uft, hp-alm

I am automating an SAP Application using UFT Tool, I have completed my Automation work in UFT and I have placed all my automation Test Scripts in HP ALM Shared Repository under the folder name Test labs and I am executing my Test scripts from HPALM.
I have a plan to automate the task of launching the HPALM and Run the Test automatically from my local machine so that the user need not need to log into the HPALM each time when he runs a Particular scenario.
In order to achieve this I have an idea to create a file on my local machine containing the name of the test cases and when selecting the Test case the script should open the ALM Connection and Run the Test, But I don't find the appropriate way to achieve this since I am a new to HPALM and VB.
Any Ideas are appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in Simpler terms you need to automate using OTA.

1 - You will need a file containing all the test cases and a Flag to check which test case to run - This file can be an Excel file.

2 - Write a VBScript to initiate ALM Connection, Read the cases to be executed from an excel file and execute its test scripts.

Read OTA for more details

Check out my answer for [How to use 'Export to HP ALM' Addin for Excel using Macro or VbScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45814380/how-to-use-export-to-hp-alm-addin-for-excel-using-macro-or-vbscript)

*You may be able to find ideas on connecting ALM through VBScript (I have used a macro, you can use a .VBS (Notepad) )*

Let me know if you need more help